# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord - making relationships errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, database-migration, relation

I am new to rails and have followed a number of guides on various online courses and using other Stack Overflow questions to generate some models (Continent, Country, State) with references and attempt to start making some instances and testing them.

```
rails g model Continent name:string
rails g model Country name:string continent:reference
rails g model State name:string country:reference
```

I do not remember which order I made them in. But I had to manually add the following in the model folders.

```
class Continent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :countries
    has_many :states, through: :countries
    has_many :regions, through: :states
end


class Country < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :continents, optional: true
    has_many :states
    has_many :regions, through: :states
end


class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, , optional: true
  has_one :continent, through: :country
  has_many :regions
end

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state, optional: true
  has_one :country, through: :state
  has_one :continent, through: :country
```

Finally, I start adding some tests to use in the seeds and console. Adding the continent works as it is simple, however, running Country.create(name:"Australia", continent: Continent.find_by(name: "Oceania")) does not build the relationship between Continent and Country (Continent_id is nil in the Country).

However, I can run just the Continent.find_by(name: "Oceania") and get:

> => Continent id: 10, name: "Oceania", created_at: "2018-09-19
>   09:18:07", updated_at: "2018-09-19 09:18:07"

I have a feeling I am on the right track but have mixed up a few things between patching together multiple solutions/methods. I may be using the generators wrong or similar, potentially mixing up some manual methods with somethings I should let the generators handle. If anyone can help fill in the gaps that would be appreciated. Here is the schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_13_044538) do

  create_table "continents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "countries", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "continent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["continent_id"], name: "index_countries_on_continent_id"
  end

  create_table "states", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "country_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["country_id"], name: "index_states_on_country_id"
  end
```

Comment: Actually, now i am starting to think that `#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Country id: 1, name: "Finland", continent_id: nil, created_at: "2018-09-19 10:05:54", updated_at: "2018-09-19 10:05:54">]> ` represents the relationship itself rather than the index to where the correct country is stored? Am I storing the wrong data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Country model, you have:

```
belongs_to :continents
```

Since `belongs_to` denotes a singular relationship (i.e., a country can only belong to one continent), you need to change this to

```
belongs_to :continent
```

Then Rails should start to assign the continent correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still getting used to the "magic" that is the automatic pluralisation, completely missed that one. I'm glad that at least the logic is okay and it was just a type (despite how frustrating it is).

Comment: Actually, I just realised another mistake, if I manually add the continent_id (e.g. 1 or 2) it would work. However, in my `Continent.find_by(name: "Oceania")` I should have actually written `Continent.find_by(name: "Oceania").id`

Comment: You don't actually need to do that unless you're setting `continent_id` directly. So it would look like `Country.create(name:"Australia", continent_id: Continent.find_by(name: "Oceania").id)`. If you just use `continent: Continent.find_by(name: "Oceania")` it should work fine. In fact, I prefer it the way you did it initially.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't realise you could do either continent or continent_id. I just got confused and tried a few different options and probably got them mixed up. Still used to working with raw databases but this is nice once you get the hang of it :) thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Rails has a lot of really convenient features that become very intuitive as you get used to it. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 0):

Before

`class Country < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :continents, optional: true
    has_many :states
    has_many :regions, through: :states
end`

After

`class Country < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :continent, optional: true
    has_many :states
    has_many :regions, through: :states
end`

**Belongs_to must be singular, in this case continent and non continents.**